# Converting graphql schema to sql schema

Tags: typeorm, typegraphql

Im trying to make a character creation system and am a little stumped on some logic/code in order to make it work.

At a high level, the model would look something like this:

```
Player {
  id: ID!
  name: string
  ...
  attributes: Attributes!
}

Attributes {
  strength: Int!
  dexterity: Int!
  ...
}
```

When a user wants to create a player, I also need to make sure that user creates an attributes object that is internal to the Player object.

I thought about just having the Attribute variables as part of the Player object, but I realised I would prefer for them to be separated so they can be categorised easier on the front end i.e. i would just need to refer to the attributes object in player when building out some html.

What I mean by this is something like `for attribute in attributes { do something }` as opposed to `do something with player.strength; do same thing with player.dexterity` and so on.

In the database itself (postgres) I understand that they would be defined in different tables where the Attributes table would have a foreign key linking to the players id.

**This is where things start becoming confusing for me.**

I dont know how to translate this graphql schema into a postgres schema. My initial thoughts are to use this schema:

```
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                        Player                           |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| id          | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| name        | varchar(255) |                            |
| attrid      | int(11)      | FOREIGN KEY                |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+

+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|                       Attributes                        |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| id          | int(11)      | PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT |
| strength    | int(11)      |                            |
| dexterity   | int(11)      |                            |
+-------------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

but that doesn't really work because it means I have to make an attributes entry before I can make a player entry seeing as I dont have access to the foreign key at creation. I was hoping that

I am not sure at this point (very new to this kind of stuff) if there is an issue with my logic here or not. I got to the point in my code where I am defining the Player Resolver and specifically the `addPlayer` mutation which is using an AddPlayerInput as shown below:

```
@InputType({ description: "Create a new Player" })
class AddPlayerInput implements Partial<Player> {
  @Field()
  name!: string;

  @Field()
  player!: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  theme?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  alignment?: string;

  @Field()
  attributes?: Attributes;
}

@Resolver(Player)
export class PlayerResolver {
  @Mutation(() => Player)
  async addPlayer(
    @Arg("data") newPlayerData: AddPlayerInput,
    @Ctx() { req }: MyContext
  ): Promise<Player> {
    return Player.create({
      ...newPlayerData,
    }).save();
  }
}
```

This will not work, and it comes with the error:

`CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError: Cannot determine GraphQL input type for 'attributes' of 'AddPlayerInput' class.`

I'm not sure what I should be doing at this point.

Ideally what I would like as the outcome is to be able to query the database with a players id and have the return value contain all the player information including their attributes in one call.

If anyone could point me to what I need to learn to make this work, or have any suggestions on my design flaws it would be very much appreciated.